# Definite article in generic reference

Tags: grammar, definite-article, generic-noun-phrases

All the grammar books that I have consulted state quite clearly that the definite article can be used in generic reference with singular count nouns, as in the following examples:

> The elephant is a clever animal

> The radio was invented in Italy

I haven't been able to find any information as to how common this use actually is though, so now I'm wondering whether this applies generally, to any countable noun in the singular, or if there are any limitations to this rule. To me, it sounds odd saying things like

> ?The woman has been marginalised throughout history

> ?The human began walking upright 6 million years ago

I would much rather use the indefinite plural form in these examples. Is this intuition (that *the* + singular count noun doesn't quite work in the latter two examples) correct, and, if so: why?

Comment: Interesting question! _The_ is commonly used in generalisations about a species of animal, but not about human beings. I don't know why.

Comment: @KateBunting Right; that's my intuition too, but, like you, I can't explain why.

Comment: What @Kate said. I'm sure that for many nouns, most if not all native speakers would agree as to whether or not the singular can be preceded by a definite article. That's to say - can we use singular ***the X*** as an alternative to plural ***Xs*** or more explicitly singular ***any X** [chosen at random from **all Xs**]*. Doubtless there will be borderline cases which some people accept and some don't (***The** Englishman is king of his castle* might be an example of such). I'm sure we'll get there, but for now I'm as intrigued as you guys when it comes to *How do we **define** the "rule"?*

Comment: This from an ELU answer looks good... [*note that the generic use of **the** is actually very restricted, in that we only use it with a relatively small selection of nouns.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/198842/2637) But as the final (recent) comment there says, *It's interesting that generic **the** can be used with species (the blue whale), higher orders (eg genera) (the oak) ... of animals, fungi, plants ... but not with 'man'.* Where by implication, "interesting" = "**inexplicable**".

Comment: A couple more that we ***can't*** say - ***The plant** is a vital part of Earth's ecology.* ***The fungus** is an interesting life-form*. They can only be expressed using either the ***plural***, or with an ***indefinite article***.

Comment: I think this use of "the" implies that all elephants, radios, etc. are interchangeable, at least with reference to what's being talked about in that sentence, or that you're referring to a hypothetical "typical elephant".  I think that's why it sounds vaguely rude to use it for humans.  A telling example: the writer John Buchan had an unfortunate habit of making statements about the outlook of, for instance, "the Jew".  Regardless of what he was saying, that would be considered very rude these days because it sounds as if he thinks all Jews are interchangeable and think the same as each other.

Comment: @A.B. Mm, interesting thought... that doesn't explain why examples such as "The plant is a vital part of Earth's ecology" (as suggested by FumbleFingers) don't work though...

Comment: @Helen I haven't the least idea!  English is strange!

Comment: @A.B. Haha, indeed! :)

Comment: "The plant" is hardly a fair comparison to "the elephant," as there are many distinct varieties of plants--are you talking about a grass, herb, shrub, or tree? (The same may be said for "the fungus." The one on my pizza is a far cry from the one attacking my foot.)

Comment: If a group of objects is represented by one object of their class, this singular countable noun takes the definite article **the** In most but not all cases

Answer (score 1):

**A notion representing a class of objects**

> **If a group of objects is represented by one object of their class, this singular countable noun takes the definite article the**. Its meaning is a notion representing *a class of objects, not the only object or specific object.* This function is called the generic function of the definite article. ***The definite article "the" in this function is used only with a singular noun, mostly with the names of animal species, plants, inventions, instruments, and some others***. Ref [Useful English](https://usefulenglish.ru/grammar/part-3-specific-use-of-the)

---

> The woman has been marginalised throughout history?

I would suggest that *Woman* in this case is not per se a singular count noun its specialised as it can only refer to a singular. Where as Bear can be Bears and Elephants can be Elephants if there friends come round. A woman must become women or people if her mates drop in.

It is more common to see the plural form used in a case like this

> > Women have been marginalised throughout history?

But you are correct "*The women*" is not used and seem to have been relegated to use for television shows only. Why we use the plura form I have no idea maybe it a solidarity thing or maybe she just got tired marching through the millennia on her lonesome. I presume that when our language was formalised **we did not, at that time, consider ourselves animals hence the missing "The"**

> The human began walking upright 6 million years ago

In this case *the word choice is incorrect* as much as I or anyone else wishes not to appear sexist. The correct choice should have been Man. Whilst it is quite acceptable to call either a bull or a cow an Elephant or a boar or a sow a Bear it. *Unfortunately it no longer seems correct to call a woman a Man.*

> Man began walking upright 6 million years ago

*But you are are correct we do not use *The Man* in this instance.* Even if he considers himself a bit of an animal.

---

**man** noun (PEOPLE);the human race: [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/man)